# using the time as a dynamic variable to compare values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on programming a page in JS that grabs calendar data from an outside source, imports it into a multidimensional array and uses it to display who is currently working along with their photo, phone number, etc.

Right now I have it set up so that the page reloads every 15 minutes. I'd prefer to have this all done dynamically so that when, say, the clock strikes 5pm the page knows to update without having to wait until the 15 minute refresh is triggered.

All of the work times are pulled from the other calendar in 24 hour format (so 5pm is 1700).

Here's how I'm generating the current time to compare with the start/end times in the calendar:

```
//Get the current date and time
var dateTime = new Date();
var month = dateTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = dateTime.getDate();
var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay();
var year = dateTime.getYear() + 1900;
//converting hours and minutes to strings to form the 24h time
var hours = dateTime.getHours().toString();
if (hours.length === 1) {
    var hours = '0' + hours
};
var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes().toString();
if (minutes.length === 1) {
    var minutes = '0' + minutes
};
var time = hours + minutes;
//convert the 24h time into a number to read from later
var timeNumber = parseInt(time);
```

I then use if statements to compare the start/end times from the imported schedule with timeNumber to determine who is currently working and push that to an array that is eventually displayed on the page with this code:

```
//figure out who is currently working and put them in the workingNow array
var workingNow = [];
for (i = 0; i < workingToday.length; i++){
    //convert time strings to numbers to compare
    var startTime = parseInt(workingToday[i][7]);
    var endTime = parseInt(workingToday[i][8]);
    //compare start and end times with the current time and add those who are working to the new list
    if(startTime < timeNumber && timeNumber < endTime){
        workingNow.push(workingToday[i]);
    }
};
```

I guess I have just been trying to figure out how to make this comparison of the data in an array with the current time something that is dynamic. Is this possible or would I need to go about this in a completely different way from the ground up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at momentjs. This is a really good library to handle all sort of time and date manipulation.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks! This will be very helpful in cutting down how much code I need to write and simplify that process. I'm relatively new to programming in general, and I guess I'm just trying to wrap my head around having a script that continually evaluates if a condition is true (i.e. if a time range from an array matches the current time) and to dynamically rebuild the page without having to refresh and re-evaluate the statement. I dug into some code to generate a dynamic clock with JS, but using if statements and such is a bit more complicated than spitting out a dynamic variable on a page.

Comment: I guess you can use setInterval to evaluate the statement at a given interval. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

Comment: Thanks, Ole, for pointing me in that direction--that's exactly what I'm looking for.